# Generate random key with verify in database with table lock

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I wonder how to correctly generate a unique string key of, say, 16 bytes and put it in the database table with validation of uniqueness. I suppose I will have to generate a key locally using Random class or `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class, then I should somehow lock interested database table for writing and check if the record with specified key already exists.

If yes, then going to another loop and repeat. If no, then insert a new record with specified key and then release database lock on that table. I do not want to use GUID, nor I want to use database auto-increment strategy. I need the key generated as atomic operation and be sure, that no other record exists for specified key. Is there a way to put a lock on table and use it on the next call to SQL Server?

Comment: Another option I see is to put UNIQUE constraint on column and insert with possible SQL exceptions. Try to insert a new random key while UNIQUE constraint is violated

Comment: Why do you not want to use GUID?

Comment: For sake of memory, I need it to generate a key for socket session, it should be relatively small and should expand to as low memory as possible. A socket session key will be stored in the database for audit & logging

Comment: Another option I see is to generate random string key in SQL Server and thus with  only a single call to server I can do everything I want

Comment: If you're happy to generate it in SQL Server, then using an [auto-increment sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will probably be the easiest thing.

Answer (score 0):

The following stored procedure should lock your table for 2 minutes. You can change the delay parameter to suit your needs.

```
BEGIN TRAN  
SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WITH (TABLOCKX)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00' 
ROLLBACK TRAN   
GO
```